cocoaasyncsocket react native - Showing All Messages Library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket
While running the react native ios application in xcode am facing this , tried pod install several but no result
pod install
Added this line
the use_frameworks!
pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'
ios/pod cache clean -all
bundle install
bundle exec pod install
this all steps i tried
